# How to invoke multiple instance of same python script from C?

Tags: python

I want to embed python in C and invoke multiple instances of same python script from C. How do I do that ?

Any example code will be helpful..  How does GIL affects me here ?

Thanks..

Here is sample program.... Which is giving wrong result.. because I have only one interpreter... I need to invoke multiple interpreter... How do I do that??

```
-------------------C Program----------------
#include "Python.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    PyObject    *pName, *pModule[2], *pFunc;
   PyObject    *pArgs, *pValue;
   int i = 0;
   int a, b;

   Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
   Py_Initialize(); /* initialize the python interpreter */
   for ( i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
       pName = PyString_FromString("scr");
       pModule[i] = PyImport_Import(pName);

    if (pModule[i] != NULL) {
           pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule[i], "add");
        if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {

            printf ("Enter the numbers to add to run: ");
            scanf ("%d %d", &a, &b);
            pArgs = PyTuple_New(2);
            pValue = PyInt_FromLong (a);
            PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue);
            Py_DECREF(pValue);

            pValue = PyInt_FromLong (b);
            PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, pValue);
            Py_DECREF(pValue);

            pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
            Py_DECREF(pArgs);

            if (pValue != NULL) {
                printf("Result of call: %ld\n", PyInt_AsLong(pValue));
                Py_DECREF(pValue);
            }
            else {
                Py_DECREF(pFunc);
                Py_DECREF(pModule[i]);
                PyErr_Print();
                fprintf(stderr,"Call failed\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else {

        if (PyErr_Occurred())
            PyErr_Print();
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find  function \n");
    }
    Py_DECREF(pFunc);
  }

 /* Print result */
  for ( i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
     // pName = PyString_FromString("scr");
    //pModule[i] = PyImport_Import(pName);

    if (pModule[i] != NULL) {
        pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule[i], "print_result");
        if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
            pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);
            if (pValue != NULL) {
                printf("Call succeeded\n");
            }
            else {
                printf("Call succeeded\n");
                PyErr_Print();
                fprintf(stderr,"Call failed\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

Py_Finalize();
return 0;
}
--------------- Python Script ---------------------
$ cat scr.py
c = 0
a = 0
b = 0

def add(a1,b1):
    global a
    global b
    global c
    a = a1
    b = b1
    print "Python: Will compute ", a,"+", b
    c = a + b
    return c

 def print_result():
     print 'Python: Result of ' , a , ' + ' , b, 'is: ', c
     return
 ---------------- Actual Output-------------------
 Enter the numbers to add to run: 2 3
 Python: Will compute  2 + 3
 Result of call: 5
 Enter the numbers to add to run: 5 5
 Python: Will compute  5 + 5
 Result of call: 10
 Python: Result of  5  +  5 is:  10 <--- PROBLEM
 Call succeeded
 Python: Result of  5  +  5 is:  10
 Call succeeded
 -------------------- Expected Output --------------------
 Enter the numbers to add to run: 2 3
 Python: Will compute  2 + 3
 Result of call: 5
 Enter the numbers to add to run: 5 5
 Python: Will compute  5 + 5
 Result of call: 10
 Python: Result of  2  +  3 is:  5
 Call succeeded
 Python: Result of  5  +  5 is:  10
 Call succeeded
 -------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The GIL is irrelevant.  Just call them as you would any other script.

Comment: I mean how can I achieve this in a single threaded program.. I mean I would like to maintain list (or array) of module handles that I import using PyImport_Import() API call... I will invoke PyImport_Import call in a for loop to instantiate the script 10 times for example... I will invoke the function in the script with different parameters... I am getting the same handle every time and it is overwriting each instance of the script..

Comment: You need to expand your question with this sort of information. Ideally include an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have added a MVCE which running into problems ( which is expected) ..Want to know how to fix it..

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There is almost certainly a better way.

Comment: I am trying to do this: Create and invoke multiple python interpreters from a single thread in C. I am not able to do that ... I found Py_NewInitialize()... But not so user friendly and it has some caveats as well..

Answer (score 2):

By importing `Python.h` and calling `Py_Initialize` you are creating a single global Python interpreter.  This keeps a dictionary of loaded modules: the second time you try to import the same module, that dictionary returns the same module as the first time.  That is how Python (and embedded Python) is usually expected to work - just like if you do a second import within a Python script.

It is *possible* to use the "sub interpreter" api to create a new sub interpreter by calling `Py_NewInterpreter()`.  This then can be used as a new interpreter with its own new module dictionary etc.  You can swap between the sub interpreters by using `PyThreadState_Swap()`.

However, I have not done this and it looks a little poorly documented.  There are some docs and in particular some caveats [here](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#bugs-and-caveats). Apparently the sub interpreters are not completely separate, though they may be sufficiently so for your purposes.

In your case I think you need not worry too much about the GIL since you are not planning to execute the two interpreters at the same time.

So I think something like this should work, though I've not tested it.

```
Py_Initialize();

// Do something in first interpreter 

PyThreadState *tstate_1 = PyThreadState_Get();
PyThreadState *tstate_2 = Py_NewInterpreter();

// Do something in second interpreter 

PyThreadState_Swap(tstate_1);

// Go back to using the first interpreter
```